# merged array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array that includes of objects and every objects includes of objects,
I want convert below array

```
[  
  { 
    0: { a: 1, b: 2 }, 
    1: { c: 3, d: 4 } 
  },
  { 
    0: { e: 5, f: 6 }, 
    1: { g: 7, h: 8 },
    2: { i: 9, j: 10 },
  } 
]
```

to this array

```
[  
  { a: 1, b: 2 }, 
  { c: 3, d: 4 }, 
  { e: 5, f: 6 }, 
  { g: 7, h: 8 },
  { i: 9, j: 10 }
]
```

[image]

Comment: your data is not valid with nested objects without property.

Comment: I attached the console log data into my question @NinaScholz

Comment: So you have objects with properties 0, 1, ... etc., which are not arrays? Nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get a flat array with assigning the objects to an array.

```js
const
    data = [{ 0: { a: 1, b: 2 }, 1: { c: 3, d: 4 } }, { 0: { e: 5, f: 6 }, 1: { g: 7, h: 8 } }],
    flat = data.flatMap(o => Object.assign([], o));

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```